# angular function on recursive child element click

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to call a function generated by recursive @Input decorator. The problem is, `(click)` event doesn't affects children. Only parents elements clicks emits an event.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {AdminCategory} from './admin-category.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'categories',
  template: `
     <div *ngFor="let cat of categories">
      <ul>
       <li>
         <span (click)="addCategory(cat)">{{cat.name}}</span>
         <categories [categories]="cat.children" </categories>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TreeView {
  @Input() categories;
  @Output() category: EventEmitter<AdminCategory> = new EventEmitter<AdminCategory>();

  addCategory(category: AdminCategory){
    this.category.emit(category);
  }
}
```

I found somewhere here on SO (unfortunately cannot find link now) that adding an `($event)` should resolve issue, so I tried this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {AdminCategory} from './admin-category.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'categories',
  template: `
     <div *ngFor="let cat of categories">
      <ul>
       <li>
         <span (click)="addCategory(cat)">{{cat.name}}</span>
         <categories [categories]="cat.children" (clickEvent)="onClickChild($event)"> asd</categories>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TreeView {
  @Input() categories;
  @Output() category: EventEmitter<AdminCategory> = new EventEmitter<AdminCategory>();

  addCategory(category: AdminCategory){
    this.category.emit(category);
  }

  onClickChild(event){
    console.log("asdas");
    this.category.emit(event);
  }
}
```

But without any results, `console.log("asdas");` never happens. Does someone know  cause of this problem? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `(clickEvent)` Where did you declare such output event?

Comment: change `(clickEvent)` in favor of `(category)`, to upload the event through the tree to the root

Comment: ohh it works! :D could you explain it a little? I know these are basic concepts but I'm pretty new in front-end technologies. Why in parent a `click` is fine, and in childrens i need to use `category` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Output property in directives or components transfers the responsibility of managing the change produced by an event to the parent through a callback. In this case, the call of the function starts on the node of tree, through the Output `(click)` and calls "recursively" `onClickChild`, with the same Output / callback method, until it reaches the root of the tree. 
In angular, that callback is an [template expression](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions).

Although all the above is not worth anything, if you use a centralized data management method like redux. 
From my experience, I recommend it since you do not have to do all of the above. Only

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppState } from '../store';
import { AdminCategory } from './admin-category.component';
import { AddCategoryAction } from './admin-category.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'categories',
  template: `
     <div *ngFor="let cat of categories">
      <ul>
       <li>
         <span (click)="addCategory(cat)">{{cat.name}}</span>
         <categories [categories]="cat.children"> asd</categories>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TreeView {
  @Input() categories;

  contructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}
  addCategory(category: AdminCategory){
    this.store.dispatch(new AddCategoryAction(category));
  }
}
```

I attach [documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md) and an [example app](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngrx/platform/tree/61cbfe537f9df8cef3dd4a6ee0b8f483e49653f4).
How to build [`AddCategoryAction`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/actions.md#typed-actions), reducer

```
import { CategoryActionTypes, CategoryActionsUnion } from './category.actions';
import { EMPTY_ARR } from '../empties';

export type CategoryState = CategoryModel[];


export const CATEGORY_INIT: CategoryState = EMPTY_ARR;

export function reducer(state: CategoryState  = CATEGORY_INIT, action: CategoryActionsUnion): State {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CategoryActionTypes.ADD: {
      return state.concat(action.payload);
    }

    case CategoryActionTypes.RESET: {
      return CategoryInit;
    }

    case CategoryActionTypes.ANOTHER: {...

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

And import to `AppModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { categoryReducer } from './category';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, StoreModule.forRoot({ category: categoryReducer })],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And you do not need to cross the tree to change or check the state

You can learn more about the advantages [here](https://redux.js.org/basics). Enjoy.

Comment: I followed your advice with using ngrx/store, I read some articles and watched some videos. I'm not sure did I understand it well but It looks like I have to `copy` whole state of my application on each event right? Let's assume I have an shop application with milion products, milion clients, orders etc... Now I just need to change a name of one product - does it mean I have to copy these all objects just to change one name?

Comment: You are not really copying, but re-pointing if it's necessary. The milion of entries you do not have ordered in the disk and the array is not static. So these data do not move from where they are. They are only deleted when they are not needed, that is, when they change, they are erased from the memory and the new value is alloc. It is similar to how memory manages languages like Rust